# Loop through several columns and rows and query based on it

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb

I'm looking to loop through the columns and rows of my dataframe and query a database.

I have a query set up and I'd like to loop down each unit and then up each date and populate the total cell with the result of the query using the install date.

For example for Part 1 Total for Unit 1, would like to use the result from the query of Unit 1 and 3/1/2019.

Hopefully I explained it sufficiently.

Thank you in advance:

---

Edit, in an effort to clarify what I meant above.

This is how the dataframe looks before I run the loop/query

```
Unit Number |Part 1 installed  |Part 1 tot | Part 2 installed|  Part 2 tot|
Unit 1          3/1/2019                       5/13/2019    
Unit 2          1/12/2019                      11/6/2019    
Unit 3          4/12/2019                      6/2/2019
```

And this is how I'd like it to look after the query is ran for each of the dates:

```
Unit Number |Part 1 installed  |Part 1 tot | Part 2 installed|  Part 2 tot|
Unit 1          3/1/2019           12225       5/13/2019           9587
Unit 2          1/12/2019          68554       11/6/2019           1557
Unit 3          4/12/2019          58774       6/2/2019           21448
```

Comment: For me, the requirement is not clear. Can you put the input & output as text into the question instead of picture?

Comment: can u share your query, it might make your question a bit clearer

Comment: u only need unit number and part 1 installed, so pull that out with a list: A = tuple(df.Unit_Number.tolist()) , B = tuple(df.Part1.tolist()), then pass the variables as parameters to your sql query using the %s or %(sth)s options. and when you are done, you can concat your result back to the dataframe and ideally create a new dataframe. it is just a shot in the dark. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

OK People I was able to figure it out, I'll leave it here in case it helps anyone else

To assign to the specific cell during the loop, you can use the .at method

df.at[[i], 'Column'] = query_result